# Any particular vacuum policy to increase performance using Drupal with PostgreSQL?

Tags: 7, performance, database

I'm running Drupal 7 with PostgreSQL as a Q&A (with a lot of nodes inserts/updates and several contrib modules). Do you recommand any particular pgsql vacuum policy on particular tables ?

Comment: For my curiosity. Why do you use PostegreSQL instead mySQL or MongoDB?

Comment: I was forced to migrate to PostgreSQL because the databases administrator decided to uniformize databases servers policies.

Comment: Off topic comment: Thats sad, when administrators force tools on developers. Maybe they should not be using drupal at all, I understand that sometimes you do need to consider skill level to manage the system, but then this doesn't make sense. I have nothing against postgres, just that its weird when this kind of stuff happens.

Comment: @Dipen While it is 'sad', it is also completely understandable from his point of view, especially <strike>if</strike> when you need to manage/scale a lot of different stacks.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can run your database optimization commands any time you want, but I think at least bi-weekly helps. However, if by running database optimization commands you intend to improve the performance of your site by more than 5%-10%, I'm afraid no vacuum optimization policy will do. You will need to utilize traditional performance troubleshooting procedures such as checking all your server's error logs, access logs, database slow query logs, as well as taking in consideration your peak and average load versus your current architecture.